# Knowrob: missing individuals

Tags: ros, knowrobtutorials, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I correctly installed knowrob and knowrob tutorials. (No warning and errors!)
then when I try to execute the tutorial and specifically to query for the individuals of Drawers, I get:

```
?-register_ros_package(ias_semantic_map). 
true.
```

And

```
?- owl_has(A, rdf:type, knowrob:'Drawer').
false.
```

While I whould get

```
 ?- owl_has(A, rdf:type, knowrob:'Drawer').
 A = 'http://ias.cs.tum.edu/kb/knowrob.owl#Drawer1' ;
 A = 'http://ias.cs.tum.edu/kb/knowrob.owl#Drawer103' ;
 A = 'http://ias.cs.tum.edu/kb/knowrob.owl#Drawer109' ;
 true.
```

I installed Knowrob by source as suggested.

Thank you in advance, I think that @moritz can help me.

And when I run:

```
nearlab@Bazinga:~/Development/ros_workspace$ rosrun rosprolog rosprolog ias_semantic_map
% library(swi_hooks) compiled into pce_swi_hooks 0.00 sec, 3,856 bytes
% /home/nearlab/.plrc compiled 0.01 sec, 1,472 bytes
%     library(error) compiled into error 0.00 sec, 19,104 bytes
%    library(lists) compiled into lists 0.00 sec, 45,824 bytes
%   library(shlib) compiled into shlib 0.00 sec, 67,120 bytes
%   library(option) compiled into swi_option 0.00 sec, 14,768 bytes
%  library(process) compiled into process 0.00 sec, 99,664 bytes
% /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/rosprolog/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 107,448 bytes
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 5.10.3)
Copyright (c) 1990-2011 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?-
```

It seems no errors or warning!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127856/knowrob:-missing-individuals/) by [Noah](https://answers.ros.org/users/8581/noah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The output you have posted is much too short, none of the KnowRob files are loaded. Have you run rosmake knowrob and did this work without problems?

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2014-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Noah](https://answers.ros.org/users/8581/noah/) on 2014-02-14**:
I edited the question! Thank you moritz!

**Comment by [Noah](https://answers.ros.org/users/8581/noah/) on 2014-02-14**:
Thank you, I missed a package! I solved it!